# Ebbinghaus 1885 memory experiment data from credible source

Tags: data-request, research

I am looking for the dataset generated from the memory experiment conducted by [Hermann Ebbinghaus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Ebbinghaus) in 1885. The experiment was described in the book ["Memory; A Contribution to Experimental Psychology"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614271666).

This is the very first experimental study on memory, and also the foundational one. It proposed stuff like [forgetting curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetting_curve), [learning curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve), etc.

I was wondering if anybody knows a credible source that provides the data from this experiment.

Ideally, it would be in digital format.

Answer (score 3):

Given the amount of time, the original data are probably no longer extant. But there is some hope, because the inheritance of Hermann Ebbinghaus was donated to the Adolf-Würth Zentrum in Würzburg, see

http://www.awz.uni-wuerzburg.de/en/news/news/single/artikel/schenkungs/

Note that you need some skills to work with this: German language, reading Old German Handwriting, maybe more ... if the desired data are part of the inheritance at all.